# Change Accordion Content

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-accordion

I have an accordion and I'd like to add/change the content inside the accordion via jquery on click.

I set up the onclick event and tried using .innerHTML='some content' 
but this doesnt work.

What am I doing wrong?

```
            <div class="panel-group">
                <div class="panel panel-accordion">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#showReq" onclick="showReqDetails"> Accordion Header</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>

                    <div id="showReq" class="accordion-body collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            this need editing
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Javascript

```
  function showReqDetails(){
    $("#showReq").innerHTML='new content';
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following:

```
$('.panel-body').html('your text here');
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Benedikt's answer, you're missing parentheses in your `onclick` event. Your code should be:

```
<div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-accordion">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#showReq" onclick="showReqDetails()"> Accordion Header</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="showReq" class="accordion-body collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">this need editing</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and, if you really want to change the contents of `#showReq`:

```
function showReqDetails(){
    $("#showReq").html("new content"); 
}
```